# Podspec The pattern INCLUDES header files that are not listed in source_files

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to create a Cocoapod. But when I run `pod lib lint` I get the below error:

```
MyCoolProject (1.0.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] public_header_files: The pattern includes header files that are not listed in source_files
```

Then it list out all my .h files. (Some removed for brevity)

```
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/MyCoolProject/Pod/Classes/Objective-C/MyCoolProject.h,
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/MyCoolProject/Pod/Classes/Objective-C/MyCoolProjectConstants.h,
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/MyCoolProject/Pod/Classes/Objective-C/MyCoolProjectEnums.h,
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/MyCoolProject/Pod/Classes/Objective-C/MyCoolProjectMacros.h,
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/MyCoolProject/Pod/Classes/Objective-C/MyCoolProject_.h,
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/MyCoolProject/Pod/Classes/Objective-C/UIView+MyCoolProjectPrivate.h, 
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/MyCoolProject/Pod/Classes/Objective-C/UIViewController+MyCoolProject.h
```

I have spent 2 days and found 0 information that helps me understand and correct the error. ***Can anyone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?***

Here is my podspec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name                = "MyCoolProject"
  s.version             = "1.0.0"
  s.summary             = "Color Framework for iOS (Obj-C & Swift)"
  s.homepage            = "https://github.com/myusername/MyCoolProject"

  s.license             = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.md" }
  s.author              = "My Name"

  s.platform            = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  s.source              = { :git => "https://github.com/myusername/MyCoolProject.git", 
                            :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/Objective-C/**/*.h'
  s.frameworks   = 'UIKit', 'QuartzCore', 'CoreGraphics'

  s.default_subspecs = 'Default'

  s.subspec 'Default' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/Objective-C/**/*.{h,m}'
  end

  s.subspec 'Swift' do |ss|
      ss.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
      ss.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/Swift/MyCoolProjectShorthand.swift'
      ss.dependency 'MyCoolProject/Default'
  end
end
```

As you can see from my screenshot all the files are there:

[image]

Comment: Did you fixed this problem? Can you share the actions, please.

Answer (score 0):

Does moving the `public_header_files` declaration into the `Default` subspec make a difference? Or moving `source_files` to the outer scope?

I suspect that CocoaPods is checking the files for `Swift` subspec before it processes its dependencies.